# How to show the simple integral is less than $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For probability measure $\mu$, I want to show that for a compact set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, the mapping
$$a\mapsto \int_{X} |x-a|^2d\mu(x)$$
is continuous.

***My idea:***

For $\forall\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ s.t. $|b-a|\le \delta$, we have
$$\bigg|\int_{X}|x-a|^2d\mu(x)-\int_{X}|x-b|^2d\mu(x)\bigg|\le \epsilon$$

Note that
$$LHS\le \bigg|\int_{X}(|x-a|^2-|x-b|^2)d\mu(x)\bigg|\le \int_{X}\bigg||x-a|^2-|x-b|^2\bigg|d\mu(x)$$

I just want to know if we can have
$$||x-a|^2-|x-b|^2|\le |x-a-x+b|^2 ???$$(Seems not true...)

Comment: The inequality is not true. Take $x=0, a =cb$ where $c$ is  small positive number.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So how to prove the function $f(a)=\int_{X} |x-a|^2d\mu(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: Use DCT or a similar result to interchange limits and integrals.

Comment: @Hetebrij Can you explain more? Do you mean $\lim_{a\to a_0} f(a)$? But why we can interchange limits? If use DCL, we need $|x-a|^2$ is bounded by a $L^1$ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any sequence $a_n \to a$, and define $f_n(x)=|x-a_n|^2$.

We have $|x-a_n|\le |x-a|+|a-a_n|$.

Since $X$ is compact and $a_n \to a$, it's not hard to see that there is some constant $C$ wish $|f_n(x) \le C$ for all $x \in X$. But $\mu$ is a probability, then every constant function is integrable. We can apply the DCT to obtain
$$\lim \int f_n  \mathrm{d}\mu=\int |x-a|^2 {d}\mu.$$

Therefore, as the sequence picked as arbitrary, your function is continuous.